# Do i need to keep register_post_type in functions.php?

Tags: custom-post-types

I am creating several custom post types, do I need to keep the register_post_type calls in functions.php? I would assume that this would only need to be run the once then removed, or do I need to keep the calls there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to keep it within `functions.php` and within the `init` hook, as it will have to register each time. It's not like with roles, where you can add it once and it's saved in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with [@Simon](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85278/14022), that you should consider to use your **custom plugin** - as it's a **best practise**. It's as [easy as creating your functions.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

What's more, you should take in consideration a [Must use plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). Again, it's not complicated and it provides the **assurance** your custom plugin containing your custom taxonomies and post types (hand coded) get's loaded.

Comment: When you say assurances, are you talking about theme changes? or something else? (thanks for the wpmu link, not come across them before)

Comment: By "the assurance" I mean that the plugin is always loaded and can not be deactivated from the administration. Thus, all custom taxonomies, custom post types, shortcodes and other things which should go to the site specific plugin. You can read more in here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/ or here: http://www.bravenewcode.com/2012/04/site-specific-plugins-a-better-alternative-to-the-wordpress-functions-php-file/

Comment: Good to know, is the Must-Use Plugins Folder (`wp-content > mu-plugins`) also works on a "stand-alone" WP instance ?

Comment: yep, it does work on single blog installation. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins#History_and_Naming

Answer (score 1):

As PHP is stateless, CPT needs to be runs for each thread and its code needs to stay permanently.

However, this leads me to the reason of my anser : instead of creating CPT in `functions.php`, best practice would be to create a plugin. The idea is if you need to change theme at some point, you will "loose" CPT ; so using a plugin allow you to have liberty of changing theme without loosing CPT data and admin UI.

Comment: I try and limit plugin use so code things like custom taxonomies and post types myself. But i see your point.

Comment: I meant custom-built plugin, of course, for your own and only use. It's just the matter of where to place the code.